# Apple ID or password entered incorrectly

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id

I just tried to update some apps but it's telling me apple Id or my password I entered is wrong (it isn't). My Apple ID is same as before.

I Then tried to reset my password.
Even after that it is still saying my Apple ID or my password is entered wrong. I chose the option to answer a security question and put the correct answer in but it tells me my information is incorrect.

I have been on the phone with Apple support this afternoon for more than 30 minutes and they still couldn’t fix it.
I know the information I'm giving is correct but Apple is still unable to help me.

What should I do?

Comment: This space is intended for "questions" ...

Comment: I would say "What should I do? " is a question

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the servers go down. If you try again in a couple of hours you may find that everything is back to normal.

I have had this happen on a few occasions.

Answer (score 0):

do you accidentally let anyone know your ID and password? You might lose your ID if they change your info. It's likely to happen.